# maven: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

Tags: maven

At execution of any arbitrary mvn command I get following warnings at the beginning of the logs:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Unfortunately, these warnings sometimes lead to errors at runtime and break my maven command execution. Does anyone know how to address this and get rid of these warnings?

**My maven version:**

```
Apache Maven 3.5.2
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.2, vendor: Azul Systems, Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/zulu-11-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-47-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Answer (score 31):

My best guess: your `guice` version is not compatible with Java 11.

Comment: Found my guice version was tied to my Maven installation. Since my distro sources weren't updated, ended up downloading Maven 3.6.2 binary from apache.org and update environment to use it rather than 3.6.0 which was on my system.

Answer (score 26):

I am using Debian and the commands below removed this warning for me.
I am also using OpenJDK 11.

```
# Download maven 3.6.3
wget https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.6.3/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz -P /tmp

# Untar downloaded file to /opt
sudo tar xf /tmp/apache-maven-*.tar.gz -C /opt

# Install the alternative version for the mvn in your system
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/mvn mvn /opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn 363

# Check if your configuration is ok. You may use your current or the 3.6.3 whenever you wish, running the command below.
sudo update-alternatives --config mvn
```

Running the final command, you should select the maven version 3.6.3.
After that the warning will be removed.

Comment: As of 2020/10/12, the instruction still works for Ubuntu 18.04. But for tar xf needs sudo also. This solution removed the warnings.

Comment: So weird that the installed version of Maven on Ubuntu, which is 3.6.3, exhibits this behavior. It must have been compiled using a different JDK or for a different target.

Comment: 3.6.3 is no longer available at this url the minimum available is 3.8.8 . 3.6.3. is on maven repo  though https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.6.3/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz

Answer (score 11):

As JF Meier mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55493563/10290286), my guice version was incompatible with Java 11. A reinstallation of maven with the [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/) resolved this issue for me.

Comment: Why not accept his answer instead of creating your own and accepting yours?

Comment: I did it because it was the way how to resolve the issue.

Comment: You should accept JF Meier answer and just put a comment there for the re-installation part.

Comment: His way of doing this is fine... the first was certainly not an answer, but simply reiterated the problem and, yes, giving a summary of the situation. The asking person added what he did to resolve his problem which is encouraged on this board.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using a custom version of Maven or maybe Ubuntu WSL, then, remove Maven, download it from official site and [install](https://maven.apache.org/install.html) it.

Example if you have WSL, assuming you have a `/c/tools` directory:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove maven
$ cd /c/tools/
$ tar xzvf /c/Users/<USER-NAME>/Downloads/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz
$ echo "PATH=/c/tools/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.profile
$ source ~/.profile
$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /c/tools/apache-maven-3.6.3
Java version: 11.0.8, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-18362-microsoft", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: This was the solution for me.  None of the others worked in WSL2.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the problem even with a recent Maven distribution. It seems that the packaged Mint version reuses the package *libguice-java* instead of using a *guice-4.2.1-no_aop.jar.*

So installing the binaries from the Maven site fixed the issue.

Comment: I just saw this comment on the guice project repo https://github.com/google/guice/issues/1216#issuecomment-742417433 inline with what you mention here

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced the issue recently and in my case I was using older version of Spring
So I changed from this

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

to this

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

and it worked for my case

Answer (score 0):

Guice has just released a new version, the [v5.0.1](https://github.com/google/guice/releases).
Upgrading to this one should fix the problem without having to downgrade your Java version from 11.

There is an [issue](https://github.com/google/guice/issues/1133) of this exact same problem in guice's github.

Comment: --not so good because you have to build and maintain it from then on. It's better to install Maven 3.6.3 *from* Apache Maven (and not from Ubuntu, Mint, etc.).