# How to hide WARNINGS when compiling a maven project?

Tags: java, maven

I need to completely hide maven WARNINGS when using `mvn clean compile` or `mvn exec:java`.
Even when I use something like `mvn clean compile -q` I got this output:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

1. I know hiding warnings may be a bad practice, but right now I need
   to do that.
2. In addition, I need to run this source code in other machines and
   I'd like to avoid to configure any classpath file or something like
   that.

Is that possible?. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: `mvn clean compile -q 2>/dev/null`

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Maven?

Comment: This issue sounds really bad ... I'd suggest reporting it (as suggested), not ignoring it.

Comment: Yes, don't incur this as technical debt.

Comment: Maybe update your versions of guice - see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55492394/maven-an-illegal-reflective-access-operation-has-occurred   and https://github.com/google/guice/issues/1216

Comment: I am using maven version 3.8.1. I mean, I do not want to get any output when executing my code. I do not want to get any "WARNING". Is there any way to ignore them?, I just want as output my code prints.

Comment: The warnings are telling you that those libraries (or more accurate the code in there) is not really correct in relationship with JDK9+ and the java module system...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe following recommendations from [Understanding Runtime Access Warnings](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/migrate/index.html#JSMIG-GUID-7BB28E4D-99B3-4078-BDC4-FC24180CE82B) would help and you could modify your `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable to allow access to the requested package:

```
MAVEN_OPTS=--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```